# How to rearrange files in Trinket?

Tags: python, file

I am using Trinket to code. I have many files in my trinket and I want to change the order of them. I couldn't find any way to move them around. If anyone knows, please tell me!

This image is an example of what I am talking about. I want to move file1.py in front of file2.py so that the files in order.

[image]